# Method vs. Function invocation pattern

Tags: javascript

I picked up this example from [taylormcgann](http://blog.taylormcgann.com/2014/01/15/invocation-patterns-javascript/). Before I ask my question, let me declare that I'm new to JavaScript and having a tough time grappling with the concepts.

In the link I mentioned, here's how the method invocation pattern is defined:

```
var person = {
    name: 'Calvin',
    age: 25,
    greet: function () {
        alert('My name is ' + this.name + '.');
    }
};
person.greet(); //My name is Calvin.
```

Fair enough. `greet()` is defined as a method, and is accessed as such. Now comes the function invocation pattern:

```
// Add a new method to person
person.calculateAge = function (yearsFromNow) {
    var self = this;

    function yearsOld() {
        return self.age + yearsFromNow;
    }

    alert('I will be ' + yearsOld() + ' years old ' + yearsFromNow + ' years from now.');
}
person.calculateAge(10); //I will be 35 years old 10 years from now.
```

I'm not able to understand how on Earth does this become function invocation? I can test and verfity that the `this` object refers to `window`, but the calling syntax is the same as above. Is this *really* the difference between method and function invocation pattern, that one is defined inside the object and one is, kind of, outside? I come from C/C++ background, so you can understand how surprising this is for me.

Any thoughts are most welcome.

Comment: If you remove the `yearsOld` function, and simply assign the value to a variable, like `var yearsOld = this.age + yearsFromNow`, would it make more sense to you?

Comment: Nope. I would still be stumped by `person.calculateAge =` . . . can't shake off the feeling that the function is attached to the object, and hence is a method. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between the `person.calculateAge` and `person.greet` as both will be added as a property to the 'person' object. However the author is trying to explain how the '`this`' keyword is set during varying execution context which normally does not depend on where the function is defined, rather it depends on how a function is invoked.
In both the cases above the '`this`' keyword will be set to '`person`' object as these methods are being invoked by 'person'.  However while invoking `yearsOld()` method it will no more point to 'person' object as it is being invoked by `person.calculateAge`.
I would recommend to take a look at [Mozilla Dev link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to understand '`this`'.

Comment: You've added an interesting perspective. Yes, indeed it is the case that `yearsOld()` is being treated differently. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 3):

I will provide you the simple example which will differentiate the method invocation and function invocation.

```
var x = 3;

var foo = {
     x: 2,
     baz: {
        x: 1,
        bar: function() {
            return this.x;
        }
    }
}

var go = foo.baz.bar;

alert(go());//3
alert(foo.baz.bar());//1
```

when you call method inovcation 'this' binds to the current object and when you call function invocation pattern 'this' binds to global object. Above example will simply explain you all things read carefully.

In your example both are method invocation patterns.

Comment: Very nice example. The JS syntax is really hard to adjust to, but I guess I'll get used to it in time. :)

Comment: I would suggest you to read a book "JavaScript: The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford

Comment: Doing that only! But it's still early stages and I'm getting confused left, right and center.

Comment: Hello @dotslash, tutorial is not incorrect, it's just not very clearly explained :). Anyways, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ is a great place as well.

Comment: Excellent example. So the Function Invocation Pattern appears like using a C++ function pointer without an implicit this.  And a typical workaround for the global scope of invocation is to set self=this and use self inside the called function.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing how you are considering the example.

If you are thinking, `person.greet();` is method invocation and `person.calculateAge(10);` is function invocation then you are wrong both are method invocation.

What I think is, in the second method `calculateAge` the way you call `yearsOld` is a function invocation pattern.

For JS reading right stuff is more important. Have a look at [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-good/9780596517748/ch04s03.html).

This is a function invocation pattern:

```
var sum = add(3, 4);    // sum is 7
```

As `add` method is not part of any object, like `yearsOld` function in example we are considering.

Answer (score 0):

Well! Although I'm new to javascript and this question is really old one. But I'm writing this answer to help new people looking for answer.

When you declare a function as a part of your object the context of **this** keyword retains to that of your current object and hence it's called ***method invocation*** but when you declare another function inside the previously declared function, this new function's **this** keyword takes the global context as it is the property of any non arrow function. This function with global context will be considered as ***function invocation***.

In the above given example the functions **greet** and **calculateAge** are under *method invocation*, while function **yearsOld** comes under *function invocation*.

For reference checkout this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrow-functions-in-javascript/